# MySql 5.5.40 stored procedure @@Identity

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, crud, identity

i've a problem in a stored procedure when i try ovverriding a variable with the value of @@Identity of the last operation. I'll write an example:

```
DECLARE out_result BIGINT(20);
SET out_result = -1;

UPDATE tableName SET name = "pippo" WHERE id = 12;
SELECT @@Identity INTO out_result;
-- here it works great and out_result value is 12

IF out_result > 0 THAN
    UPDATE otheTableName SET address = "Route 666" WHERE id = 37;
    SELECT @@Identity INTO out_result;
END IF;
```

I expect that if the first operation was successfull, the variable out_result is greater than 0 and now the code will do the second update and it's so.
After the second update (but it may be also a delete for example) i expect that out_result variable will take the value of the second update (in this example out_result = 37) but it's not so. Here out_result is still equal to 12. Some idea will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `@@Identity`??? are you talking about `MySQL` or `MSSQL` here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is no `@@Identity` in `MySQL`. You must have mistaken and probably talking about `SQL Server`. Coming to your case, if you are still getting `out_result = 12` then I believe the corresponding `UPDATE` statement (as pointed below) didn't processed any row because the condition `WHERE id = 37` didn't matched (OR) have returned `FALSE`. You can check and verify the same using `@@ROWCOUNT` system global variable.

```
UPDATE otheTableName SET address = "Route 666" WHERE id = 37;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm working on a pre-existing project and i've found this use of @@Identity still utilized. I'm talking surely about MySql. If you are right... now the strange thing is: "Why it works in the first case?". In any way is @@ROWCOUNT a safe way to obtain the same information?

Comment: I've tried also to store the @@Identity value of the second update in a different variable, and i obtain "null", but in the database the update has been done succesfully. The strange thing is that in the first update I obtain as @@Identity exactly what i expected from. I'm confused... In any way: what is the safest method in MySql 5.5.40 to obtain the ID of the last operation executed?

Comment: There is no `@@IDENTITY` in `MySQL` to be honest; you definitely have mistaken. In `MySQL` you should use `LAST_INSERT_ID` instead.

Comment: You're right LAST_INSERT_ID seems to work correctly. @@Identity seems to be introduced in some last release of MySql o support compatibility with SQL Server, but it has a lot of working problem and it is not officially documented. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kapilsoni: Please ask a new question if you have one.